# Ruby: split string in hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a string

`str = "race_1: 650m, 215m, 265m, 315m\r\nrace_2: 165m, 215m, 265m, 315m."`

Expected result: I wanted to split this in a hash like this:

```
hash = {
   race_1 => [650, 215, 265, 315],
   race_2 => [165, 215, 265, 315]
}
```

Can someone please guide me in a direction to create the matching hash?

Comment: Break it down into smaller parts: Split on the `\r\n` sequence, then split on `:`, then split on `,`.

Comment: thanks, @tadman please can you show me how to do it?

Comment: @Manav : Did you read the Ruby Docs about the `String#split` methods?

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: Your keys in `hash` are not valid Ruby objects (unless they are methods defined offstage). Perhaps they should be strings (`"race_1"` and `"race_2"`) or symbols (`:race_1` and `:race_2"`). Is the period at the end of `str` a typo?

Answer (score 4):

When the input always follows the same pattern, then I would use `String#scan` with a Regexp to extract the significant values.

```
string = "race_1: 650m, 215m, 265m, 315m\r\nrace_2: 165m, 215m, 265m, 315m."
regexp = /(race_\d+).*?(\d+(?=m)).*?(\d+(?=m)).*?(\d+(?=m)).*?(\d+(?=m))/

string.scan(regexp)
#=> [["race_1", "650", "215", "265", "315"], ["race_2", "165", "215", "265", "315"]]
```

These nested array of values can then be transformed into an hash like this:

```
string.scan(regexp).to_h { |values| [values[0], values[1..-1]] }
#=> {"race_1"=>["650", "215", "265", "315"], "race_2"=>["165", "215", "265", "315"]}
```

And because you want the numbers in the array to be integers:

```
string.scan(regexp).to_h { |values| [values[0], values[1..-1].map(&:to_i)] }
#=> {"race_1"=>[650, 215, 265, 315], "race_2"=>[165, 215, 265, 315]}
```

Answer (score 2):

The following allows any number of races and for each race to have any number of associated distances (in `str` below there are four).

```
str = "race_1: 650m, 215m, 265m, 315m\r\nrace_2: 165m, 215m, 265m, 315m"
```

```
str.gsub(/(\w+): ((?:\d+m, *)*\d+)/).with_object({}) do |_s,h|
  h[$1] = $2.split(',').map(&:to_i)
end
  #=> {"race_1"=>[650, 215, 265, 315],
  #    "race_2"=>[165, 215, 265, 315]}
```

---

This employs a little-used (and greatly undervalued) form of [String#gsub](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.3/String.html#method-i-gsub) that takes a single argument but no block, and returns an enumerator. The enumerator merely generates matches of `gsub`'s argument and therefore has nothing to do with string replacement. This form of `gsub` is sometimes a convenient replacement for [String#scan](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.3/String.html#method-i-scan) when `scan`'s argument is a regular expression that contains one or more capture groups.

The regular expression that is `gsub`'s argument can be expressed in *free-spacing* mode to make it self-documenting.

```
/
(          # begin capture group 1
  \w+      # match >= 1 word characters
)          # end capture group 1
:          # match a colon
[ ]        # match a space
(          # begin capture group 2
  (?:      # begin non-capture group
    \d+    # match >= 1 digits
    m,[ ]* # match "m," followed by >= 0 spaces
  )        # end non-capture group
  *        # execute preceding non-capture group >= 0 times
  \d+      # match >= 1 digits
)          # end capture group 2
/x         # invoke free-spacing regex definition mode
```

Note that in free-spacing mode spaces that are part of the expression must be protected. There are various ways of doing that. I have enclosed each space in a character class (`[ ]`).

---

In the example above we compute the following enumerator.

```
enum = str.gsub(/(\w+): ((?:\d+m, *)*\d+)/)
  #=> #<Enumerator: "race_1: 650m, 215m, 265m, 315m\r\n
  #     race_2: 165m, 215m, 265m, 315m":
  #     gsub(/(\w+): ((?:\d+m, *)*\d+)/)>
```

The elements it will generate are as follows.

```
enum.next
  #=> "race_1: 650m, 215m, 265m, 315"
enum.next
  #=> "race_2: 165m, 215m, 265m, 315"
enum.next
  #=> StopIteration: iteration reached an end
```

Note also that

```
arr = "650m, 215m, 265m, 315".split(',')
  #=> ["650m", " 215m", " 265m", " 315"]

arr.map(&:to_i)
  #=> [650, 215, 265, 315]
```

---

A variant of this is to write

```
rgx = /\w+: (?:\d+m, *)*\d+/

str.gsub(rgx).with_object({}) do |s,h|
  key, value = s.split(':')
  h[key] = value.split(',').map(&:to_i)
end
  #=> {"race_1"=>[650, 215, 265, 315],
  #    "race_2"=>[165, 215, 265, 315]}
```

As the regular expression now has no capture groups we get the same result when the first line is replaced with

```
str.scan(rgx).each_with_object({}) do |s,h|
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write this code

Input

```
str = "race_1: 650m, 215m, 265m, 315m\r\nrace_2: 165m, 215m, 265m, 315m."
```

Code

Split the code with colon : and replace the m at the end

```
hash = str.scan(/(race_\d+): (.*)/).each_with_object({}) do |(race, distances), hash|
  hash["#{race}"] = distances.split(', ').map { |d| d.sub(/m$/, '').to_i }
end
p hash
```

Output

```
{"race_1"=>[650, 215, 265, 315], "race_2"=>[165, 215, 265, 315]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try the code below?

```rb
str = "race_1: 650m, 215m, 265m, 315m\r\nrace_2: 165m, 215m, 265m, 315m."
rows = str.delete('.').split("\r\n") # => ["race_1: 650m, 215m, 265m, 315m", "race_2: 165m, 215m, 265m, 315m"] 
hash_result = {}
rows.each do |row|
  key = row.split(':').first # => race_1
  value = row.split(':').last.split('m, ').map(&:to_i) # => [650, 215, 265, 315]
  hash_result[key.to_sym] = value
end
# hash_result = {:race_1=>[650, 215, 265, 315], :race_2=>[165, 215, 265, 315]}
```

p/s: I think you should do it yourself to improve yourself

Answer (score 0):

Is this the expected output?

```
require 'yaml'

str = "race_1: 650m, 215m, 265m, 315m\r\nrace_2: 165m, 215m, 265m, 315m."

races = YAML.load(str)

races.each { |k, v| races[k] = v.scan(/\d+/).map(&:to_i) }

pp races
```

produces

```
{
   "race_1" => [650, 215, 265, 315],
   "race_2" => [165, 215, 265, 315]
}
```